# Git reset failing after find and replace

Tags: php, git, git-commit

No git's command is working anymore  created a branch, made some commits. Then I made a recursive find and replace as so :

```
LANG=C find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec sed -i '' s/My\ sentence/My\ sentencevotre/ {} +
```

which worked properly, but now I can't commit, I can't reset hard, I have a serie of messages when reseting : 
error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-$SHA.pack does not match index
...

and when commiting :

warning: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-$SHA.pack cannot be accessed
....
error: invalid object 100644 $SHA for 'Doxyfile'
error: Error building trees

How can I manage this ?

Comment: Try to undo your changes on .git folder. If this does not work you may crashed your repository irreparable.

Comment: @Hikaru-Shindo, it is catastrophic... Do you know how I can find the name files which .git/objects/pack/pack-$SHA.pack are related to ?

Comment: No, I'm not really well informed about git's internals. If this did not help you will need to restore from a backup or create a new repiository. If you have set up a remote repository you may clone a new copy - then the loss would not be total.

Comment: Do not manually modify files under `.git` unless you really know what you're doing. This sounds like you've destroyed your repository. Hopefully you have a clone of it somewhere that you can recover from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with corrupt git repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569172/problems-with-corrupt-git-repo)

Answer (score 1):

Undo your find and replace and try again. Maybe you are lucky enough ... otherwise use your backup.

Be more careful with your .git directory next time.

Comment: Do you know how I can find the name files which .git/objects/pack/pack-$SHA.pack are related to ?

Comment: No, I'm not an expert with the internals of git. I know that all important data is secured with checksums, so that git won't let you work with inconsistent data (exactly what you are experiencing right now)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you changes files inside you .git folder, which defines the repository. I don't know any other solution for that than deleting .git folder and recreating a new git repository inside the folder. This shouldn't be a big problem if you have a remote repository like GitHub.

Comment: No I didn't use github fir that... Do you know how I can find the name files which .git/objects/pack/pack-$SHA.pack are related to ?